# Covering maps of two strange topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm studying for an exam and came across the following problem.

"Let $X=\{(z_0,z_1)\in \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C} :z_0\neq z_1\}$ and let $Y=\{\text{All monic Quadratic Polynomials in a complex variable}\}$. Explain why the map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ given by $f(z_0,z_1)=$Polynomials with roots $z_0$ and $z_1$ is a covering map"

My idea for an explanation was to start by considering an open set in $Y$ but the question does not provide a specific topology to work with for $Y$. I was wondering are there any theorems for covering maps that may be used here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The map $f$ is not even well defined, let alone a covering map. For example, what is $f(1,-1)$? Is it the polynomial $z^2-1$? Or $1-z^2$? Or $3-3z^2$?

You could make it well defined by redefining the space $Y$ as the set of all *monic* quadratic polyomials (those whose $z^2$ coefficient is equal to $1$), and then the map becomes $f(z_0,z_1) = (z-z_0)(z-z_1)$.  But it's not a covering map because it's not surjective. For example, the polynomial $z^2$ is not in its image.

Do you want to rethink the question?

Comment: I left out the monic part by mistake and have edited the question. The question says specifically for $Y$ all polynomials of the form $z^2+bz+c$ for complex variable $z$. It doesn't put any constraints on $a$ or $b$, are so would making them nonzero fix the question?

Comment: No, because of the issue of surjectivity. The polynomial $z^2$ is still not in the image of $f$.

Comment: But if $a$ and $b$ are nonzero then that polynomial isn't in $Y$?

Comment: @Crunch: Huh? You said $Y$ is the set of all polynomials of the form $z^2  + bz + c$.  What's $a$? The polynomial $z^2$ is certainly of this form, with $b=c=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $b$ and $c$ nonzero

Comment: By your definition, any polynomial of the form $z^2+bz+c$ is in $Y$. It makes no difference whether $b$ and $c$ are zero or not.